# Error: Application-defined or object-defined when trying to hide row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide rows in a table based on certain criteria. I have the code working to find the cells and now I am trying to hide the other rows but when I do I get the following error:

> "Run-time error: '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Here is my code:

```
'Intiansiate objects and setup variables
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim c As Range
Dim colStartDate As Range
Dim FoundDate As Date
'Set object/variable values
Set tbl = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table1")

With tbl
    'Search "Start Date" (Col2), top to bottom, searching for the first cell with a color index of 35 and the "End Date" (Col3) which has an index color of anything other than 35
    Set colStartDate = .ListColumns("start date").DataBodyRange
    For Each c In colStartDate.Cells
        If c.Interior.ColorIndex = 35 And c.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> 35 Then
            FoundDate = c.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c

    For Each c In colStartDate.Cells
        If Not c.Hidden = True Then
            If Not c.Value >= FoundDate Then
                c.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End With

MsgBox FoundDate
```

Comment: which line? Adding where the program fails will help a lot.

Comment: If Not c.Hidden = True Then

Comment: Try `c.EntireRow.Hidden = True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [`Range.Hidden`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hidden) docs:

> The specified range must span an entire column or row.

Use `c.EntireRow.Hidden = True`.